# Does VLC use different binaries for various Linux distributions?

Tags: linux, vlc, linux-distro

My Java application uses VLC's binaries (VLCJ) for video playback in my app. I've managed to package the proper binaries for Windows and Mac (by using the compiled versions located on the VideoLAN site).

However, for Linux, it seems tougher. I was wondering if Linux also had its own different binaries for different distributions too, causing it to be more complex. I haven't see a clear answer about this so I am not sure whether it is true or not.

Comment: Most distributions have compiled their vlc.  Unless two distributions are *very* closely related, you're unlikely to find identical binaries.

Answer (score 0):

For Linux, each distribution handle the building, packaging and distribution of VLC on their own. There are useful links to most used Linux distribs on the [videolan download page](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/#download).

There is also a [snap for VLC](https://snapcraft.io/vlc) which is more universal, but using those binaries with your app may not be trivial.

For nightly builds by videolan for any platform, check this [link](https://artifacts.videolan.org/vlc-3.0/).

Comment: Wow ... snaps come a hefty "cost" in terms of size; "vlc" natively installed on Ubuntu 20.04 is ~ 61 MB .... 309 MB for the snap. I guess on modern disks that's nothing - wonder how it affects the memory footprint, too, though ...